# How to use continuous query to query out delayed data stored in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now trying to test continuous query in Apache IoTDB. My data stored to IoTDB may be delayed due to network factors, so I want to know these late data will not be queried out when executing continuous query, right? If I want to be able to query out some of these delayed data using continuous query, what configurations can I change in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sacrifice some real-time performance to achieve the calculation of the past time window in Apache IoTDB. You can also increase the calculation load and repeatedly calculate some time windows to achieve calculating the past time windows. This can be adjusted by changing the parameter `start_time_offset`, which specifies the start time of each query execution window, and `end_time_offset`, which specifies the end time of each query execution window.